# MongoDB PHP Driver

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I tried to copy my MongoDB project and database to other computer, but i can't install MongoDB PHP Driver correctly.

I'm using 32bit system and my php version is 5.5 and my php extension build is TS, VC11. I tried copying .dlls: 
php_mongo-1.6.8-5.5-vc11 and i also tried with older version and php_mongo-1.6.0-5.5-vc11.dll.

My Mongo version is 3.06, and I already added extension line in my php.ini file.

I really checked everything, and I have no idea why it's not working. Any advice would be golden. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: not working? as in crashes? doesn't show up in phpinfo()?

Comment: no, it doesn't show in phpinfo, and MongoClient function doesn't work when i try to start my application

Comment: then the dll isn't being loaded, and you'll have to check php's logs to find out why (wrong place/wrong path, wrong version, etc... or even wrong php.ini file)

Comment: when i right-click on wamp -php - php extensions it does show up, but it still doesn't show in phpinfo. I checked both php.ini in apache->bin folder and in php folder. My phpinfo also shows this path: Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\Windows but i can't find it there

Answer (score 1):

Its better to install [Bitnami WAMP Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) and download PHP Version 5.5.30 which is currently recommended by Bitnami. The benefit of Bitnami over XAMPP is that they already provide MongoDB Driver installed so you don't need to configure `php.ini` configuration file.

- Note: MongoDB works best with 64-bit operating systems while 32bit has limited storage upto 2GB.